# How to check if Windows is busy by installing any driver?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, driver

I write program which installs usb device driver by means of dpinst.exe. At program start I want to check if Windows is busy by searching/installing/updating some driver. (Main scenario I want to avoid is launch of dpinst.exe while Windows is searching driver for plugged device.) How can I check that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is to use CMP_WaitNoPendingInstallEvents function. Example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff537895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.getprocesses) to look if another instance of dpinst is already running.

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach(Process p in processlist){
    if (p.ProcessName.StartsWith("dpinst"))
      ...
}
```

I would bet that this is unnecessary : the scenario you are trying to avoid is already being managed by dpinst/Windows itself.

Comment: Thanks for your proposal but I start only one instance of dpinst. And if Windows is busy with another searching/installation at that time  then dpinst process may take up to several minutes to complete installation. So I want to warn user and let him decide whether  continue and wait or close another installation and retry.